# Hidden Markov Model on R Studio

Tags: machine-learning, r, markov-hidden-model

Is there any detailed materials that can help explain how to set up HMM on R Studio?

Comment: have you seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1r5XTqrCTQ)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at [here](http://hiddendomains.sourceforge.net/). As you can read from there:

> 1. Download and unpack hiddenDomains
>
> If you haven't already done this, download the latest version of hiddenDomains from the Sourceforge [website](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hiddendomains/)
>
> Now unpack it

```
shell$ tar -xzvf hiddenDomains.VERSION.NUMBER.tar.gz
```

> Where VERSION and NUMBER represent the release that you downloaded.
>
> 2. Install R and required R packages (if necessary)
>      Download and install R if you don't already have it.
>
> If you don't already have them, you will need to install two hidden Markov model libraries:
>
> [depmixS4](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/depmixS4/index.html)
>   [HiddenMarkov](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HiddenMarkov/index.html)
>   You can do this by starting R on the command line:

```
shell$ R
```

> Or, if you prefer RStudio, you can use that.
>
> Regardless of how you started R, type the following commands to install the packages.

```
> install.packages("depmixS4")
> install.packages("HiddenMarkov")
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678786/rstudio-hiddenmarkov-package-and-dthmm-function) and [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjPv8q-q-nYAhXHLFAKHXU1BsQQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2FHMM%2FHMM.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1ywdsUCA92akpljCkPV2N0) may also be helpful for knowing how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called ‘HMM’ (not 'hmm').
You can find the documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HMM/HMM.pdf).
There are a lot of tutorials available.

Answer (score 0):

Use depmixS4 package in R. This basic example would help-

https://machinelearningstories.blogspot.com/2017/02/hidden-markov-model-session-1.html

depmixs4 vignette is also present. u can get in package also.

A simple code sample would be-

R Code snippets-

### Required library

library(depmixS4)

### data loading-

physician_prescrition_data <-c(12,16,45,45,56,67,78,98,120,124,156)

### model execution-

HMM_model <- depmixS4::depmix(physician_prescrition_data~1, nstates = 2,ntimes=length(physician_prescrition_data))

### model fitting

HMM_fm <- fit(HMM_model)

### Transition probabilties-

HMM_fm@transition

### posterior states-

posterior(HMM_fm)
plot(ts(posterior(HMM_fm)[,1]))

### Emission probabilties-

HMM_fm@response